# eclipse-ee on linux: Refusing to initialize GTK+

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk

I have just installed eclipse-ee 4.2 on linux (Debian Jessie AMD64).

Starting eclipse gives the following error:

```
(process:6511): Gtk-WARNING **: This process is currently running setuid or setgid.
This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create a helper
program instead. For further details, see:

    http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html

Refusing to initialize GTK+.
```

There is no file setuid or setgid. I have extracted the tar.gz-archive using `tar -xzf ...`
Unfortunately the mentioned URL http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html does not exist any more.

Any ideas? TIA!

Edit: I created a bug-report for this problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using OpenJDK instead of Oracle's JDK.